# django channels routing error

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm doing chat application with django-channels but I have strange routing error.

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'META'
```

so here is my routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route, include

from chat.consumers import ws_connect, ws_message, ws_disconnect
from chat.views import chatmain 

http_routing = [
    route("http.request", chatmain, path=r"^/chatwindow/$", method=r"^GET$"),
]

chat_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_connect),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect),
]

channel_routing = [
    include(chat_routing),
    include(http_routing),
]
```

I want then I follow /chatwindow link to use normal view and unload chat application but it won't work.

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using Channels 2? You're posting channels 1 code but if you installed from PIP you probably got Channels 2. The message object might of had a META property in Channels 1 but they moved everything like that into the scope property on Channels 2.